# Boyd & Vandenberghe, example 5.6 — formulation of norm approximation problem

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

In Example 5.6 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), the problem is

$$ \text{minimize} \quad \Vert Ax - b\Vert,$$

where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is any norm. Reformulating by introducing a new variable, we get:

$$ \text{minimize} \,\, \Vert y\Vert \quad s.t. \, Ax-b=y$$

The Lagrange dual of this problem he claims is:
$$ \text{maximize} \,\, b^T\nu \quad s.t. \Vert \nu\Vert_{*} \leq 1 \quad\text{and} \quad A^T\nu=0$$

My question is, is this correct? For my dual formulation I am getting:
$$ g(\nu)=\text{inf}_y \{ \Vert y\Vert - y^T \nu \} - b^T\nu,$$
taking into account that $A^T\nu=0$.

Using the fact that the dual of norm is the indicator, I get the dual as:

$$ \text{maximize} \,\, -b^T\nu \quad s.t. \Vert \nu\Vert_{*} \leq 1 \quad\text{and} \quad A^T\nu=0$$

That has a negative sign. I cannot seem to understand where I am making a mistake. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In general, for a constraint $x=y$, write the Lagrangian with a $\nu^{T}(x-y)$ term or with a $\nu^{T}(y-x)$ term.   When you solve the Lagrangian dual problems for these two formulations you'll see a difference in sign in $\nu$ depending on whether you used $x-y$ or $y-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally: $\min_x \|Ax-b\| = \min_x \sup_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1} \nu^T(Ax-b) 
= \sup_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1} \inf_x \nu^T(Ax-b)$.

Note that if $\nu^TA \neq 0$ we can pick $x$ so that $\nu^T(Ax-b)$ is unbounded below, so
$\sup_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1} \inf_x \nu^T(Ax-b) = \sup_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0} \inf_x \nu^T(-b) = \sup_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0}  -\nu^Tb$ and hence
$\min_x \|Ax-b\| = \max_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0} \nu^Tb$.

**Elaboration**:

Note that
$\max_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0} -\nu^Tb = \max_{\|-\nu\|_* \le 1, (-\nu)^TA = 0} -\nu^Tb = \max_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0} \nu^Tb $.

Comment: I guess I got everything similar up to your 2nd to last step. I guess I just wanna know how the following is equivalent:

$$\sup_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0}  -\nu^Tb = \max_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0} \nu^Tb$$.

I mean aren't we flipping the sign? Is maximizing $-\nu^Tb$ and $\nu^Tb$ the same thing? Could you please explain this part?

Comment: Well, no, $\nu$ is a variable and $\nu$ satisfies the constraints **iff** $-\nu$ does, so I can replace $\nu$ by $-\nu$ everywhere.

Comment: I am very sorry if this is too trivial, but I am still a bit confused. Could you please further explain how you came to the conclusion: $\nu$ satisfies the constraints **iff** $-\nu$? I feel like I am almost there. Thanks a bunch for taking the time.

Comment: Just change variables, let $\mu = -\nu$ then $\max_{\|\nu\|_* \le 1, \nu^TA = 0} -\nu^Tb = \max_{\|-\mu\|_* \le 1, -\mu^TA = 0} \mu^Tb$ and note that $\|-\mu\|_* = \|\mu\|_*$ and $ -\mu^TA = 0$ **iff** $ \mu^TA = 0$.

Comment: The change of variable only works because the constraints are 'immune' to a sign change.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense now. Really appreciate your time!

Comment: Glad to be able to help.